# Django update student data from loop

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am new to development and dont have much idea about this please help me, I am unable to get the code for taking id of the absent student using javascript please help me with it.

This is my html code where the list of students is displayed, all student by default are present and I if i mark some student as absent all other students should be saved as present and other marked as absent which were selected

HTML code

```
<div class="container">
  <form method="POST" action="takeattendance">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4 style="color:white;"> Select Subject For Attendance</h4>
      <select class="btn btn-success" name="subject">
          <option selected disabled="true">Subject</option>
          {% for sub in subjects%}
          <option value="{{ sub.id }}">{{sub.subject_name}}</option>
          {%endfor%}
      </select>
  </div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="color:white;"><b>Email</b></th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:white;"><b>Roll No.</b></th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:white;"><b>First Name</b></th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:white;"><b>Last Name</b></th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:white;"><b>Year</b></th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:white;"><b>Division</b></th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:white;"><b>Batch</b></th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:white;"><b>Attendance</b></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for student in students %}
            {% if user.staff.class_coordinator_of  == student.division and user.staff.teacher_of_year == student.year %}
          <tr>
            <td style="color:white;"><input type="hidden" name="student_name" value="{{student.id}}" >{{student.user}}</td>
            <td style="color:white;">{{student.roll_no}}</td>
            <td style="color:white;">{{student.user.first_name}}</td>
            <td style="color:white;">{{student.user.last_name}}</td>
            <td style="color:white;">{{student.year}}</td>
            <td style="color:white;">{{student.division}}</td>
            <td style="color:white;">{{student.batch}}</td>
            <td>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="btn btn-success" name="status" id="status">
                    <option selected value="Present">Present</option>
                    <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
                </select>
                </div>                 
            </td>
          </tr>
          {%  endif %}          
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody> 
      </table>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg ">Add</button>
    </div>
    </form>
 </div>
```

Views.py

```
def takeattendance(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    subject = Subject.objects.get(id=request.POST['subject'])
    student = Student.objects.get(id=request.POST['student_name'])
    status = request.POST['status']
    print(subject)
    print(student)
    print(status)
    attendance = Attendance(subject=subject, student=student, status=status)
    attendance.save()

    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.user_type == 2:
        return render(request,'ms/hod/Attendance.html')

    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.user_type == 3:
       return render(request,'ms/staff/Attendance.html')
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Failed")

else:    
    return HttpResponse("Failed")
```

Please help me with it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes inside your **views.py**

```
def takeattendance(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        subject = Subject.objects.get(id=request.POST['subject'])
        student_ids = request.POST.getlist('student_name')
        status_list = request.POST.getlist('status')

        attendance_objs = []
        for sid, status in zip(student_ids, status_list):
            attendance_objs.append(
                Attendance(
                  subject=subject,
                  student=Student.objects.get(id=sid),
                  status=status
                )
            )
        
        Attendance.objects.bulk_create(
                attendance_objs
        )

        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.user_type == 2:
            return render(request,'ms/hod/Attendance.html')

        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.user_type == 3:
           return render(request,'ms/staff/Attendance.html')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Failed")

    else:    
        return HttpResponse("Failed")
```

I've taken status as a list of values and I've used **[`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)** to combine two lists **`student_ids`**, **`status_list`** and then taken **sid**,**status** from that.